# glyphicon в Bootstrap'e рисуется над таблицей

Tags: css, bootstrap

В моем проекте есть одна скроллируемая таблица и одна "не скроллируемая" (закреплены первые два столбца). В скроллируемой таблице у меня есть кнопочки:

[image: деловой кот]
<sub>(источник: [cs625116.vk.me](http://cs625116.vk.me/v625116007/52128/IfPHXfr-0WU.jpg))</sub>

При скроллировании таблицы, эти кнопочки, почему то, рисуются над не скроллируемой таблицей (таблице с заголовками).

[image: деловой кот]
<sub>(источник: [cs625116.vk.me](http://cs625116.vk.me/v625116007/52121/KmTAuKB6-nw.jpg))</sub>

Такая проблема возникает только с ними, ни как не могу разобраться в чем проблема =(

Comment: помимо скриншотов в тексте вопроса должен быть Ваш код или ссылка по которой сообщество может воспроизвести Вашу проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Той табличке, которая не скролится, задал `z-index: 2`, и все, теперь кнопочки "под ней".